# Elasticsearch Top level aggregation / search body metadata

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-query

It's possible to include sub-aggregation [metadata](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/agg-metadata.html) like so:

```
GET kibana_sample_data_flights/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": ...,
  "aggs": {
    "by_delay": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "FlightDelay"
      },
      "meta": {                <---
        "key": "val"
      }
    },
    "by_cancelled": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Cancelled"
      },
      "meta": {                <---
        "key": "val"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, there are dozens of such sub-aggs and some shared metadata. Although it only applies to the aggs, I wouldn't mind putting it somewhere in the `query` section. So is there a per-search-body metadata field?

I'm thinking I could wrap all these sub-aggs inside of a `match_all` filter group:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": ...,
  "aggs": {
    "meta_parent": {
      "filter": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "meta": {
        "shared": "meta"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_delay": ...,
        "by_cancelled": ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any `query` part, I would leverage the [`global` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html), like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "meta_parent": {
      "global": {},
      "meta": {
        "shared": "meta"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_delay": ...,
        "by_cancelled": ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, what you suggested with a `filter/match_all` aggregation can work, too:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "meta_parent": {
      "filter": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "meta": {
        "shared": "meta"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "by_delay": ...,
        "by_cancelled": ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `global` would not take into account the `query`, wouldn't it?

Comment: No, but as you don't have any query part, that's why I suggested the global aggregation

Comment: Gotcha. My bad -- I do have a query that needs to apply.

Comment: Then yes, if you have a query part, the filter/match_all aggregation that you suggested would be a viable alternative to the global aggregation.

Comment: Yes but we came back to my original suggestion. I was hoping there's indeed a solution without the extra `meta_parent `.

Comment: Nope, I don't see how it would be possible.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this!